# JavaScript copy textarea value to clipboard not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use javascript to copy the contents of a textarea to clipboard and its not working. When I check the clipboard its empty. My Javascript is:

```js
function copyStudentEmails() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyStudentEmail = document.getElementById("student-emails");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyStudentEmail.select();
  copyStudentEmail.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied student emails to clipboard");
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" id="student-emails" class="form-control" disabled required>@studentEmails</textarea>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copyStudentEmails()">Copy</button>
```

The contents of the textarea are visible but the copying is not working. The alert at the end of the javascript function is displayed but the clipboard is empty.

Comment: Use `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you omit the `disabled` attribute:

```js
function copyStudentEmails() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyStudentEmail = document.getElementById("student-emails");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyStudentEmail.select();
  copyStudentEmail.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied student emails to clipboard");
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" id="student-emails" class="form-control" required>@studentEmails</textarea>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copyStudentEmails()">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to use camel casing for ids. Try the below

```
    document.querySelector("textarea").select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
```

Also, remove the `disabled` property from your text area.